# Alterar a cor de fundo Intel xDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Colegas.

Estou desenvolvendo um app mobile pelo Intel SDK, porém quando visualizo diretamente no navegador ou emulador, o fundo aparece branco, mas quando visualizo pelo meu celular (Android 6.0), o fundo é preto.

Já tentei colocar no `body`:

```
background-color: white; //tentei também em hexadecimal
```

Mas mesmo assim continua preto.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou aplicar o !important no css?

```
background-color: white!important;
```

E veja se nenhum outro arquivo está acessando as propriedades do body. ;)